# is it necessary to define name in columnInfo annotation?

Tags: kotlin, android-room

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
var name: String
```

if i make model like is it work or not?

```
@ColumnInfo
val name: String,
```

Answer (score 2):

`@ColumnInfo`  annotation is needed if you want to give your table's column name a value other than your variable name.

If you want the same name for column and your variable, then it is not necessary to provide `ColumnInfo` annotation at all. But if you want your database column to read lets say `student_name` and your variable to read `name` then you would write something like:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "student_name")
val name: String
```

You could also put the same in both the variable name and the column info just for the sake of verbosity

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
val name: String
```

Comment: @SyedBabarKhurshidAnwer You're welcome. Could you please mark the answer as Accepted.